# How can I have Rye return invalid commands in ruby

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

Here is the code I am using:

```
require 'rye'
r = Rye::Box.new("ip_of_server", :user => "username_of_server", :password => "password_of_server", :safe => false)
r.execute("which testing")
```

I get the following:

```
(cmd: which testing; status: 1)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rye-0.9.13/lib/rye/box.rb:855:in `rescue in run_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rye-0.9.13/lib/rye/box.rb:804:in `run_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rye-0.9.13/lib/rye/box.rb:473:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):64
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I know it does not exist but would like to accept the error status of 1 and get the data of "which: no testing in (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin) (cmd: which testing; status: 1)"

I have attempted to modify Rye::Rap but it seems everything I do does not change the outcome.

I know I can do a rescue when I run r.execute and have the value get returned to a variable, but would like to know if there is anyway when using Rye if I can just accept the failure.

```
    irb(main):012:0* begin
    irb(main):013:1*   r.execute("which testing")
    irb(main):014:1> rescue => e
    irb(main):015:1>   merp = e.message
    irb(main):016:1> end
```